control file wo/ overwriting specific records in table
I have a table that is populated from 2 sources, and the records in the table are differentiated by a column_type (1 and 2)
let s say that column_Type =1 is for data coming from a file
And column_type = 2 for data coming from some sort of calculation on DB
Am using sql loader to load the file to this table for colum_type =1 and the control file is written to "replace into table"
=> This is causing a deletion of all records including the ones with column_type =2
The purpose of the ask here is that I am trying to figure out a way to load the data file into table for column_type =1 without impacting the records of column_type = 2 (to note that the rows might be common between the 2 column types)
So, do we have any ways to do/have this kind of control file?
I checked what are the possible options in control file between append, update and using WHEN condition but I don't think it answers the above need.


... control file is written to "append into table" => This is causing a deletion of all records

I doubt it. REPLACE does that, not APPEND.

If you want to have a better control over the process, consider switching to external table feature. Behind the scene, it still uses SQL*Loader, but source file (that contains data you're loading into the target table) acts as if it were an ordinary Oracle table.
There are some prerequisites, though: generally speaking, file can't reside on your own PC (unless it is a database server) so DBA has to create directory on the server and grant appropriate privileges (at least read) to Oracle user who will be accessing it.
You'd then be able to use (PL/)SQL to read data from external table using usual SELECT statement, e.g.
insert into target_table (id, name, ...)
select id, name, ...
from external_table s
where ...
  -- skip rows that already exist in target table for column type 2
  and not exists (select null
                  from target_Table t
                  where t.id = s.id
                    and t.column_type = 2
                 )

If you want, no problem in writing a stored procedure which will further manipulate data - various calculations, updates, deletes, whatever you want.

Right! by mistake mentioned append instead of replace.
Great point about external tables, will give it a try
